# Caja "Right Click" auto resize menu issues

Tags: caja

I have Ubuntu 20.04 Mate edition.
When I right-click on a folder or in places right pane folder, it shows a little menu with arrows to find the rest of the menu commands which is so annoying. It was not the case before, this started to happen about two months ago.
I have been searching for a config file to change that behavior to no avail.
I attached a screenshot of the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution.
When I reset the pane border-line, it enlarges the left side space view and then the Right-Click menu on devices icons looks normal.

[image]